# How do I use escape_javascript with Rails 3.0.8 and beyond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is fixed in Rails 3.0.9 now.  raw() is no longer necessary.

If you’re using js views and partial html replacements, Rails 3.0.8 is totally broken. Right after the 3.0.8 release, 3.0.9rc1 was released which partially addresses the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After upgrading, you have to wrap every escape_javascript call with raw() if you want your javascript to replace HTML. This was absolutely *not* the case with 3.0.7.

So, `escape_javascript('<img src="lolcat.jpg" />')` becomes `raw(escape_javascript('<img src="lolcat.jpg" />'))`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed when this issue is solved: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1589

Comment: Well, even in 3.0.9rc3 it doesn't work.  How are they going to keep a stable release broken for over a week?